# cout char* printing address instead of value

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, iostream, cout

In a template class, I overloaded the ostream<< operator with the following:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out,
        const DataItem<T> &cDataItem) {
    out << cDataItem.m_value;
    return out;
}
```

And `m_value` is declared as a pointer to the generic type

```
T *m_value;
```

But for some reason, when I cout the object, it prints an hexadecimal value, which I guess is the address and NOT the value, as I expect:

```
Value: 0x7fff418f9d40
```

I learned that cout with a char* should print the content of the char*, not the address. Why then is this happening? Is the template a problem?

Comment: Try `out << *(cDataItem.m_value) ;`

Comment: Unless `T` is `char` or `const char`, the behavior of `cout` is correct.

Comment: If you believe `T` should be `char` then post a test-case. Not enough info provided so far.

Comment: The code as it is is available at [Github](https://github.com/ranisalt/INE5408/tree/master/Trabalho%202) but it is quite long to be posted here, I guess. @MichaelWalz it did not work and printed a strange string `�s��`. @RSahu T is `char[40]`.

Comment: @ranisalt: Use `std::string` instead of `char[40]`. Or use `std::vector<char>`, or `std::array<char,40>`.

Comment: Note that if T is char[40] then m_value is a pointer to a char array, not the pointer to the first element of that array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char *` is a special case. For any other pointer, unless you have some specialization you implemented yourself, outputting a pointer outputs that pointer, not what it points to.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that in your case, `T` is `char[40]` which is a pointer already (equivalent to `char*`). This means that if you use `T*`, it becomes `char**` and that's what you are trying to print. Since it's a pointer to the pointer, generic template for pointers get applied and the address is printed.

For a test, you may try to print:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out,
        const DataItem<T> &cDataItem) {
    out << *cDataItem.m_value;
    return out;
}
```

In this case, you will dereference the pointer to the original value, that is `char[40]` and you should get the expected output.

---

Also, I think your `operator=` is wrong. Since you pass `T` to it, and assign it to `T* m_value`, you implicitly store a pointer to a local value. You probably want to make it take `T*` likewise in the constructor. Or a `T&` reference in both cases.

Comment: This way I get even stranger values, not even representing chars, like `0�
          ��`. Is this some problem with encoding?

Comment: I think it's more of a problem with the code. I've just updated my answer to note that `operator=` seems wrong. Try to set your compiler to higher warning verbosity (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra` in gcc).

Comment: Compiler outputs no error. I noted something, if I do `DataItem<char[40]> _(&input); std::cout << *_.value();` in the `Interface::input()` method, it outputs the value fine. Past this point, everywhere in the code, it outputs wrong. I'm confused.